# Phalcon very slow using Phalcon\Http\Response();

Tags: php, phalcon

I am experiencing a very strange issue with Phalcon.
Whenever I use `Response` inside a controller the framework becomes very slow.
Here is my simple controller:

```
<?php

// file: app/controllers/TestController.php
use Phalcon\Mvc\View;

class TestController extends ControllerBase
{

 private $response;

 public function initialize()
 {
  $this->view->setRenderLevel(View::LEVEL_NO_RENDER);

  $this->response = new Phalcon\Http\Response();
  $this->response->setStatusCode(200, "OK");
 }

 public function indexAction()
 {
   $this->response->setContent("phalcon")->send(); // very slow
 }

}
```

Whenever I use `new Phalcon\Http\Response();` Phalcon becomes very slow. For example testing it with:

```
ab -c 50 -n 100 ...
```

Request/sec: **10**

If I use a blank Controller I get

Request/sec: **1000+**

The route is:

```
<?php
//file: app/config/routes.php

$router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router();
$router->add("/:controller/:action", array("controller" => "test", "action" => "index"));
```

I tested it on AWS:

```
c4.large
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6 (cli) (built: Feb 13 2015 19:17:11)
2 cpu - 3.75gb ram
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6
```

We experienced the same behavior on a Macbook pro with osx 10.10.1

The problem is when I call the `send()` method on the response:

```
$this->response->send(); // slows down everything
```

### Note

As suggested by @Phate01 I tried `return $response;` instead of `$response->send();` and it is still very slow

Comment: tried to test it out. On [skeleton](https://github.com/phalcon/skeleton-single) project, once I made your changes, I have 3ms response time, so it may be not a case of that `$response`, but implementations using it. Using Phalcon 1.3.2. Anyway, $this->response property is already declared during `Phalcon\Mvc\Controller`

Comment: thanks @yergo! without using `$response` (with a blank controller) how much does it take?

Comment: quite the same, cant exceed 3ms except when changing template it jumps for 100ms for recompilation - just one refresh.

Answer (score 2):

I went to this page: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/response.html
and they say that

> If you are using the full MVC stack there is no need to create responses manually. However, if you need to return a response directly from a controller’s action follow this example:

```
<?php
class FeedController extends Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{

    public function getAction()
    {
        // Getting a response instance
        $response = new \Phalcon\Http\Response();

        $feed = //.. load here the feed

        //Set the content of the response
        $response->setContent($feed->asString());

        //Return the response
        return $response;
    }

}
?>
```

As you can see it return directly the `Response` object.

I guess that you should call the `->send()` outside the controller, and also adding some headers would help

Comment: Thanks @Phate01! I have tested it on my server with `return $response` but still it is very slow. It is even slower, now  `Request/sec: 2`

Comment: It's weird beacuse Phalcon is supposed to be one of the fastest php framework for what concerns http requests. However at this point I think that this is a framework bug, because we did as written in the docs and it's still super slow

Comment: That is the same thing I thought too :)

Comment: Dillo che sei italiano! :D

Comment: Anything in your `ControllerBase` implementation?

Comment: No, that is an alias for `Phalcon\Mvc\Controller`