# Phalcon very slow when I use Http\Response::send

Tags: php, phalcon

I built a Micro application, everything works fine. But performance tests shows a frustrating results. The application is very slow :

```
ab -n 1000 -c 50 http://myproject.net/
```

Normal results:

```
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   58.083 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Non-2xx responses:      1000
Total transferred:      578000 bytes
HTML transferred:       189000 bytes
Requests per second:    17.22 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       5808.272 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       58.083 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          9.72 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

After I comment **$response->send();** test results becomes better :

```
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   7.960 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      166000 bytes
HTML transferred:       0 bytes
Requests per second:    125.62 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       796.048 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       7.960 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          20.36 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

In the index file I defined the response object as a shared service :

```
$di->setShared(System::RESPONSE, new App\Http\Response());
```

**App\Http\Response** is a class extends \Phalcon\Http\Response to allow me add some headers required in my application

```
namespace App\Http;

class Response extends \Phalcon\Http\Response
{
    public function getDefaultErrorMessages()
    {
        return $this->defaultErrorMessages;
    }

    public function setDefaultErrorMessages($messages)
    {
        $this->defaultErrorMessages = $messages;
    }

    public function setErrors(array $messages)
    {
       $this->validationErrors = $messages;
    }

    public function setErrorContent(\Exception $e, $developerInfo = false)
    {
        $errorCode = $e->getCode();
        $statusCode = 500;
        $message = 'Unspecified error';

        $error = [];
        if ($this->validationErrors) {
            $error['errors'] = $this->validationErrors;
        }


        $this->setJsonContent(['error' => $error]);
        $this->setStatusCode($statusCode);
    }


    public function setJsonContent($content, $jsonOptions = 0, $depth = 512)
    {
        parent::setJsonContent($content, $jsonOptions, $depth);
        $this->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $this->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
        $this->setHeader(
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
            'Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-Authorization'
        );

        $this->setContentType('application/json');
    }
}
```

All my code is wrapped in a try-catch statement in the index file. 
I tried to make an error in order to throw an exception, if the the exception is thrown by Zephir test shows fast results, while if it is thrown by our code testshows same slow results.

When I use -k modifier of 'ab' results becomes much better :

```
ab -k -n 1000 -c 50 http://myproject.net/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phalcon very slow using Phalcon\Http\Response();](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982613/phalcon-very-slow-using-phalcon-http-response)

Comment: I just wrote some more details trying to explain the issue

Comment: Are you returning response object? Or true, or false? Please show me what you are doing in your controllers so it may behave this way.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have your View component disabled? Why are you sending response, when it is sent in other parts of code?

In one of my projects, I do have an Api module. This API module has disable Views globally:

*app/modules/api/Module.php*

```
    public function registerServices($di)
    {
        // ....
        $di->getView()->disable();
    }
```

After that I am sure no kind of view related service will be build here. In Api controllers namespace I have my base for them

*app/modules/api/controllers/controllerBase.php*

```
<?php

namespace Application\Api\Controllers;
use \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class ControllerBase extends Controller {

    /**
     * Captures method result and tries to make a JSON response out of it.
     * 
     * @param \Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher $dispatcher
     * @return \Phalcon\Http\Response
     */
    protected function afterExecuteRoute($dispatcher) {
        $content = $dispatcher->getReturnedValue();

        // some logic for prematurely generated content (debugs/warnings)
        // ...

        if(is_object($content)) {
            if(is_callable(array($content, 'toArray'))) {
                $content = $content->toArray();
            } else {
                $content = (array) $content;
            }
        }


        $this->response->setContentType('application/json', 'UTF-8');

        $this->response->setJsonContent($frame);

        return $this->response->send();
    }
}
```

So what I return from my actions are arrays with proper results.

Why to return response? Because you are [ommiting a lot of logic](https://api.phalconphp.com/source/Phalcon/Mvc/Application.html) at first place. Also [send action itself](https://api.phalconphp.com/source/Phalcon/Http/Response.html) is doing some overload, so best way would be to:

```
        // from previous code frame
        $this->response->setJsonContent($frame);

        return $this->response; // no send() here
    }
}
```

and in *index.php*:

```
echo $application->handle() // returning instance of Response
         ->getContent(); // getting content to echo
```

Please check out your code, because it is not first time someone occurs problem with his Phalcon slowing down because of `send()` method. You may be lucky one to find why if you start to change your code. My guess is for views generation.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will try to disable the view globally. Although the application is an API so there is no views it just returns processed data. I will try your solution and tell you the results.

Comment: If you do not need any view in your application (just an API), try using `$application->useImplicitView(false)` on your `Phalcon\Mvc\Application` instance.

Comment: The results still the same in my local machine, I'm still not sure what is the exact reason of this. The test results are a bit good comparing to other projects, although I expected to be a bit more better. 
For example I noticed that a piece of my code which loads all services in my controllers affects the test results by increasing at least 11 seconds to the total test time : "the code in the next comment".
Howerver I'm still waiting to upload the project to a server, then I will post back my feedbacks.

Comment: `abstract class Services
{
    private static $services = [];

    public static function getService($name)
    {

        if (! isset(static::$services[ $name ])) {

            static::$services[ $name ] = static::get($name);
        }

        return static::$services[ $name ];
    }

    public static function get($name)
    {

        $className = "\\Services\\Service\\{$name}";

        if (! class_exists($className)) {
            throw new Exception("Service {$className} doesn't exists.");
        }

        return new $className();
       }
    }`

Comment: Above code may issue with instantiating every service even if it is not in need of actual request.

Comment: The function called 'getService' creates a singletone instance of a service, so each instance is created just for once. moreover I call this function just whenever the service is needed. if you still see its not that correct please feel free to reply. thanks :)

Comment: Dear @yergo  I uploaded the project to a server I tested it using apache benchmark and the results were pretty good for me **ab -n 10000 -c 500 -k** it shows **requests per sec : 204 , time per request : 2449 ms**. I guess these results are good isn't it? . however I send response in index.php not in **afterExecuteRoute** and I have view disabled.